# Send UIPanGesture translation to all views in array

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to move all views in my array at the same time. But it doesn't work. Only the first view I touch is moveable then.

I don't want the other views to move to the same exact spot, I just want all views in the array to move the same amount of distance and speed as the view being panned. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all your views to a common superview (if not already) and add the `UIGestureRecognizer` to this common superview ;)

This will make it easier to manage for you (only one `UIGestureRecognizer`) and will move all the subviews alltogether.

Comment: Would that not move the superview as well? I have a ton of other views on the same superview that I don't want to move.

Comment: Yes that will move the superview as well that's why I suggested you to move all the views you want to move in a common superview. This common superview does not need to be visible onscreen (it can have `[UIColor clearColor]` as the background color)

Comment: Ah, I see... Is this the only way to achieve this effect? I'll update my question to give more detail about what I'm ultimately doing this for. I'm not sure if this solution would be the best.

Comment: The only other solution I see is to manage the pan youself, namely use the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to be notified of pan gestures on the view that have been touched... and in the selector associated with the `UIGestureRecognizer`, not only translate the view being touched but also all the other views you need to move along with the first one. After all, that's up to you to implement the target/action you associate with the `UIGestureRecognizer` so you can do whatever you want with it ;)